# How to get redirect url on blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I play a video url using streaming player on blackberry. If the url returns "200" status code it play successfully.

When i pass the below url, it returns "302" http status code.It won't play on streaming player.

http://belointr.rd.llnwd.net/KGW/ea398ac7b03a91c2ddf451f1fd7e3ef87f19da59_fl9.mp4?x-belo-vsect=kgw-basketball

When i check the statuscode for 302 its says redirect url.

When i pass the url on browser, it calls automatically below the redirect url.

http://belointr.vo.llnwd.net/kip0/_pxn=2+_pxI0=Ripod-h264+_pxL0=undefined+_pxM0=+_pxI1=A21907+_pxL1=begin+_pxM1=+_pxR1=13737+_pxK=20558/KGW/ea398ac7b03a91c2ddf451f1fd7e3ef87f19da59_fl9.mp4?x-belo-vsect=kgw-basketball

How can i get the redirect url programatically on blackberry.?

pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the headers of the response, retrieve the value of the header 'Location', it contains the redirect url. This is standard in HTTP protocol

Edit: Real quick sample on how to get the location header (could be written a lot better and safer)

```
    URL url = new URL("http://some.url");
    int responseCode = -1;
    while (responseCode != 200) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode > 299 && responseCode < 400) {
            url = new URL(conn.getHeaderField("Location"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi. thank u for ur info. could u explain how to retrieve the value of the header location.

Comment: Not all `3xx` response codes are redirects (`304` is not), and not all `3xx` redirects provide a `Location` header (`300` does not).

Comment: Once again thanks. But still i need one help.  import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

which are not supported in blackberry.For the HttpURLConnection,i have found a corresponding class in blackberry api,its called HttpsConnection.But for the URL class i am not being able to find any corresponding class in blackberry api.Kindly help.

Comment: I used below code. But it returns null value,            HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url+suffix);
String url = httpConnection.getHeaderField("Location");

Comment: Just tested the url above and it returns the following Location: rtsp://belointr.qtod.llnwd.net/a6405/o45/KGW/_tr_/b4/d9/9c/ea398ac7b03a91c2ddf451f1fd7e3ef87f19da59_fl9_b4d99cfab5f14c2ed67f7d1dcf48ec02.3gp but not `null`